# Handle button click in another application

Tags: c#, winapi

I am looking for a method to get a button press event, something similar like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752306%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which is used to retrieve a pointer right after an event is fired. The button I mean is located on any particular windows application I set as a target (.eg windows media player's Play button). If you know what message to catch right after I click the Play button.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is Global Mouse Hook. You can take a look at this article: [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx)

Once you handle CLICK event, you can use API functions to get Application / Control under the cursor ([WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Here is one more article with code sample that will help you: [.NET Object Spy and InvokeRemote](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/objectspy.aspx) (this is similar to spy++)

You cannot do this without using windows native methods.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas !

Answer (score 1):

User tagged this in winapi. He probably already knew about hooks. Part of HABJAN reply point to the right direction. Answer to the question is: Use Spy++
I don't think there's a message for "button clicked" or "url link clicked" but if you observe a program with spy++ you'll see there's UI notification messages like these ones: WM_CAPTURECHANGED, WM_CHANGEUISTATE or even WM_POSCHANGING. I think these are the messages you are looking for.

Another way to do this may be to use the AutomationElement, see this answer: [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)

PS: If I could downvote an edit by another user to a question, I would downvote Dyppl's edit... question used very precise words: "get message" instead of "handle" in the title. 
PS2: It's an old question but I was asking me the same question earlier and came across it on google, maybe my answer will help someone

Comment: Thanks for your ideas !