# C# Get Chorme's open tabs Urls

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url, tabs

I am trying to Get All of chrome's open Tabs urls. I am using the following code:

```
 private string GetBrowserURL(string browser)
        {
            try
            {
                DdeClient dde = new DdeClient(browser, "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
                dde.Connect();
                string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
                string[] text = url.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                dde.Disconnect();
                return text[0].Substring(1);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

But keep getting the following error:

> The client failed to connect to "chrome|WWW_GetWindowInfo"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)