# Get Chrome URL List and total Instance Detail in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I want to get list of Chrome browsers running currently, for example 
how many windows(instance) of Chrome browser are opened and in each window list of URLs, so that  I can store each URL under its specific windows(instance).

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(Generic.fileType.chrome.ToString());
foreach (Process p in localByName)
{
}
```

using this code I can't differ windows and processes.

Comment: Not so easy - have a look at [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This is kind of broad task... please first find out some approach by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This greatly depends on what your main purpose is but you might want to check out the [Selenium Web Driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It will make your life a 100 times easier if you need to do things with Chrome (or other browsers such as Firefox, IE, and Safari).

Comment: Actually i want to save these instance with URLs so i can reuse them later