# track google chorme URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get url of all tabs I found this code 
this code give me tabs title only please tell me how I get all tabs url

```
 var automationElements = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

// Find `New Tab` element

var propCondNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
var elemNewTab = automationElements.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, propCondNewTab);

// Get parent of `New Tab` element
var treeWalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
var elemTabStrip = treeWalker.GetParent(elemNewTab);

// Loop through all tabs
var tabItemCondition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
foreach (AutomationElement tabItem in elemTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, tabItemCondition)) {
    var nameProperty = tabItem.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
    Debug.WriteLine("title: " + nameProperty.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)

Comment: So, to get this straight: you want to get the URL's of all open tabs in a browser?  That sounds a bit dodgy, and insecure.

Comment: @AGB thank u i have already tried this but its give me only current tab URL ,i want solution for all opened tab

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet yes the above code give me titles of tabs only and i want URL