# copy the content from Google chrome’s active tab, using C#-WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome

Is there a way to copy  the content from Google chrome’s active tab to a string / text file using C#-WPF?

Example: 
Say I have three sites are opened in Google chrome,  (google.com, cnn.com & stackoverflow.com) and active tab is stackoverflow.com. The program should give me all the text (like if you do CTRL+A and CTRL+C).

I have found the way to get the active tab:
[Getting the current tab's URL from Google Chrome using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897070/getting-the-current-tabs-url-from-google-chrome-using-c-sharp)

I have done similar with IE.

```
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ieInst in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
{
  String url = ieInst.LocationURL;
    if (url.Contains(textBox1.Text))
    {
      ieInst.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_SELECTALL, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);
      ieInst.ExecWB(SHDocVw.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_COPY, SHDocVw.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT);

      TextBox1.Paste();
    }
}
```