# C# get mouse button interactions form other applications

Tags: c#, windows, user32

I want to write a program in C# that can detect mouse button interactions with ui elements in other apps and get information regarding the ui element that was interacted with and its parents, specifically an identifier for those elements that is the same every time the program is run.

For example if the user clicks on a button in another app using the mouse, my code should detect button click and get a unique identifier for that button.

Comment: Have you done any research on this subject?

Comment: Have a look at [Handle button click in another application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7242794/5552166)

Comment: It would help if you tell us what this program is supposed to do with such info?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) Nuget package.
For Example, you can detect double click like this

```
 Hook.GlobalEvents().MouseDoubleClick += async (sender, e) =>
 {
      Console.WriteLine($"Mouse double click = {e.Button}");
 };
```